# Migration between Oracle and Azure SQL Data warehouse using SSMA

Tags: sql-server, azure, oracle-11g, data-warehouse

I am facing the below error while syncing table from Oracle to an Azure SQL data warehouse using SSMA tool (a tool used to migrate data from Oracle to Azure SQL). I am able to connect to the database and convert the schema from Oracle database but, am getting an error while syncing it with the Azure SQL data warehouse. Please suggest a solution.

> Errors: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.
>
> Synchronization error: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.

I am unable to identify the rectification of this error in SSMA. Would help lots to know the resolution.

Comment: I'm no DBA, but it sounds to me like the `USE` statement isn't supported to switch between databases. I'd recommend using a new connection to connect to a different database.

Comment: do u know what SSMA is ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe SSMA supports Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Can you provide a link to the download so everyone is clear which tool you are using?

What about an SSMA migration to a SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition instance, followed by using the [Azure SQL Data Warehouse Migration Utility](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-migration-utility/) to migrate SQL to Azure SQL DW?

The two step migration is because SSMA doesn't support Azure SQL DW, and the Azure SQL DW Migration Utility doesn't yet support Oracle.

Comment: Hi , here is the download link:
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=43689

Comment: @shreya that's what I expected. So my recommendation holds. Thoughts?

Comment: thanks a lot that s a very good recommendation. I need your help regarding another issue with SSMA... My server side migration setting doesnt seem to work.. it fails without any error message. Any fix resolutions you can suggest to me?

Comment: @shreya no clue. Open a support case I suppose